# несколько php.ini на apache2 сервере

Tags: lamp

Добрый день

Подскажите, есть apache2 сервер, на нём крутиться несколько сайтов. В некоторых случаях необходимо на каждом сайте указать своё значение в php.ini.

Вариант php_admin_value в хосте, не совсем то, что нужно. А несколько php.ini апач подгрузить не дает, по крайней мере поиск в гуглах не дал нужного результата(

Comment: Поделитесь, с какой целью Вам это необходимо? Уверен что на 90% файлы мало чем будут отличаться.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно для каждого сайта создать свой фаил php.ini
[тут инфо как это сделать](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php)